# Room attempt to re-open an already closed database

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

When using Room from the Android Architecture Components, I received the following error when attempting to access the database using a Dagger component:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: (database path)
```

I was using Dagger version `2.11` and Room version `1.0.0-alpha7`. The error was reproducible on version `1.0.0-alpha5`.

This error occurred on any attempt to access the database through a DAO after initialising the database and injecting it into my class.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's because you are trying to modify the schema of the existing database without giving it any migration information. So basically it attempts to write the new database schema to the existing DB which doesn't work.

There are two ways around this. If you are in your development environment what you can do is fallback to a destructive migration, to do this your database creation code would look something like the following:

```
MyDatabase myDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase.class, "my-db")
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build();
```

This means when you provide the database with an updated or new entity it will do what the answer from @huw said and just delete the database on the application's installation removing all the data from it and give you a fresh install.

The other method is to use a migration function. They are pretty long so unless someone wants me to write it up here I'll leave it for now but basically, the documentation can be found here:

[Room DB Migration Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#db-migration)

This essentially causes the DB to run some SQL provided by yourself to update the database to the new version. This way you can ensure that none of your data is lost while doing the migration; or as little as possible depending on what you are doing. This is the preferred method for production apps as it means users won't lose their pre-existing data and you won't get a lot of angry reviews/lost customers.

Hope that makes helps!

Comment: Remember to change database version in @Database annotation. fallbackToDestructiveMigration() will not reset DB just because DB structure is changed.

Comment: I know this is a bit late but someone still having the same issue can refer below GitHub issue.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/285#issuecomment-448850055

Comment: I had provided the migration information but, still got the error! `.PDatabase$Companion$MIGRATION_3_4$1.migrate (PDatabase.java:195)`

Answer (score 17):

One solution to this problem was to delete the database file and start again. This was not an issue since I was only testing and could repopulate the database using online data.

To do so either:

- App info > Storage > Clear Data
- Manually remove the file at `/data/data/com.app.example/databases/database.db`

Comment: The path of /data/data/.... is not directly accessible to the android device, it should be rooted device to access that path of file.

Comment: Correct — I was developing on a rooted device, so this was able to work for me. (Unsure, but you might also be able to do this through adb?)

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of exception after not so successful migration. Always double-check the SQL query you use for a migration. You can create a new column with a wrong type of data and the exception's description won't be helpful.