# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, android-room, illegalstateexception

I have this problem with Room, which detected by Yandex Metrica on devices with first install from Market, so it can't be a migration issue. I also tested it on different real and AVD devices and couldn't reproduce it. According to Yandex Metrica logs this issue can be reproduced on android versions from 5.0.1 to 9.

Room version: 1.1.1

I think my issue is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283268/fatal-exception-java-lang-illegalstateexception-attempt-to-re-open-an-already), but there is no right answer there.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/one.sendy.messenger/databases/Socialmessanger_database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1861)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1840)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:150)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.hasRoomMasterTable(RoomOpenHelper.java:151)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:123)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:115)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:151)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:411)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.compileStatement(RoomDatabase.java:244)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.createNewStatement(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:65)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.getStmt(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:72)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.acquire(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:87)
        at com.social.soc.repository.repositorycore.daos.ChatMessageDao_Impl.deleteAll(ChatMessageDao_Impl.java:697)
        at com.social.soc.repository.repositorycore.Repository.clearDatabaseSync(Repository.java:680)
        at com.social.soc.repository.repositorycore.Repository.lambda$deleteAllData$37$Repository(Repository.java:669)
        at com.social.soc.repository.repositorycore.-$$Lambda$Repository$Wk_rZJ-sdwid6vlvxvXj1SzYXr8.run(Unknown Source)
        at beta.framework.android.util.async.AsyncWorker$AsyncTaskExec.doInBackground(AsyncWorker.java:51)
        at beta.framework.android.util.async.AsyncWorker$AsyncTaskExec.doInBackground(AsyncWorker.java:39)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        ... 3 more
```

Here is what I am doing with db:

```
chatMessageDao.deleteAll();
```

And in Dao:

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM chatmessage")
    void deleteAll();
```

It is not a migration issue, because:
1) it is first install;
2) it reproduced on 5% devices;
3) and if it was problem with migrations it usually says what it "expected" and what "found".

Also I found this [issue](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/453) on GitHub, that leads me to this [one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124476912). Looks like this issue actually existed, but they fixed it in Room 2.1.0. But my gradle says that latest version is 1.1.1. And also I'm using support libs and not an androidx.

**Update:**

I migrated project on androidx, fixed a few conflicts, and everything seem to work fine. But because I can't reproduce this issue, I will report on that question later, if it helps.

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: @frankenstein Which part of code do you need?

Comment: Please show the code which does the work assigned to AsyncTask

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan this is not my question

Comment: `on devices with first install from Market,` OP states that this is for first installations, why would the migration code be relevant @MuhammadFarhan ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes, that's my point. If it is not migrations, than what?

Comment: no idea, does seem quite interesting for this to happen for fresh installations

Comment: @ksnorth check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376492/room-attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-database

Comment: @frankenstein this question is about migrations, and in my case migration isn't a problem.

Comment: @ksnorth which line exception thrown?

Comment: @Mr.AF it is thrown by the line that I mentioned in my question: chatMessageDao.deleteAll();. And it is a first query to my db.

Comment: @ksnorth what's the purpose of putting migration class here?is the issue related to migration ? i don't think so .in deleteall do you only execute DELETE FROM ....?

Comment: @Mr.AF I put there because of guys that asked for this earlier. Yes, in deleteAll I do only DELETE FROM. This function exist to delete everything from tables, so after chatMessageDao.deleteAll() I call like 7 another similar functions, to clear all tables. But as crush logs said it crashed on chatMessageDao.deleteAll().

Comment: @ksnorth i think i can fix your problem. if i could i will post you.

Comment: @Mr.AF thanks, it would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in a later version of Room. There's no use in trying to solve it on the version you're currently using. Please update because the version you're using is almost 2 years old

Checkout this link to see which version is the latest: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

Comment: I'm using support libraries. And this one androidx. And it's probably no way to use only androidx.room and support libs together. And migration from support to androidx will be really painful.

Comment: Migrating to AndroidX will happen automatically. There's a feature for it in Android Studio

Comment: Yes, I know. It is not in migration process deal, it is a big project and we're using a lot of different libs, and I don't know how it's gonna effect them. It is a compatibility question.